# Changing suffix of template in after effects

Tags: after-effects

I am totally new to after effects and I make teaching videos. I want to change suffix "K" to "%" but I am having a hard time removing it from the template I have bought from an online store. I have tried to contact them through the mail but I have not received any email yet so it's getting delayed.

What I see is when I delete the value control layer they get removed but inside that layer, I am not able to see any option of changing it so there must be something inside of it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Google Drive [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s0jVEnhA5n4-ZLZmt9aYlkGrNNuMg-Bq/view?usp=sharing) for reproducibility. I am using slide 14. Please guide me.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where is the "suffix" you want to change?

Comment: The red layers are the text layers. If you select one and hit `EE` (double-tap the letter e) you should see some expressions. If one of these is for `source text` post that expression in your question.

Comment: @Matt See labels on points on line graph.

Comment: @stib Wow thank you so much could elaborate and write an answer so that we can close this question by a tick?

Comment: Sure, if you post the expression on the source text, I will try to fix it for you

Answer (score 1):

The text labels are all controlled by a simple expression that takes the value of a slider, converts it to an integer and adds the letter "K" at the end. Even without programming skills you can see where the "k" part happens (but I put in some magic sparkles to give you a hint). Simply replace the letter "K" with "%" and you're golden.

[image]

I wrote a script that finds and replaces text in expressions. You can get it [here](https://blob.pureandapplied.com.au/find-n-replace-for-expressions/). I'd suggest if you use it that you search and replace the whole line (`x + "K"`), as just replacing the letter k with % may ma%e other expressions stop wor%ing.

Also, I hope that the project you linked is just a dummy project. I doubt the client would be happy with you posting details of their presentation on the public internet without their approval. At the least it could get you fired.